# How can I make this sentence unambiguous?

Tags: punctuation

I'd like suggestions to punctuate, or if necessary, reword the following sentence, so as to give its explicit meaning, but without losing its feel.

> I encourage thought and discussion provoking questions by students.

I'd like to leave it as is, and just punctuate it if possible.

The meaning I want is "I encourage students to ask questions which provoke thought and discussion".

I'm concerned that as is, it could be read as "I encourage thought and discussion, which will provoke questions by students".

Edit:

It seems even in my attempt to be explicit, I was still ambiguous. I'll try again.

My intended meaning is: "I encourage students to ask questions which provoke **both** thought and discussion".

Comment: To make a written sentence unambiguous, say it out loud. You'll have to settle on one pattern for rhythm and intonation, and that will disambiguate. There are several ways to intone the sentence, depending on which constituents the speaker chooses to link together, and their differences are all audible. Virtually all ambiguity occurs in writing only.

Comment: @John: I'm not sure it's even *possible* to force the unambiguous interpretation OP intends in normal speech. The best I can think of is to leave an exaggerated pause after ***thought*** if you want to unambiguously indicate that you *don't* want that word to apply to ***provoking***. But if that's what you *do* want, I don't see how you can make it crystal clear that you're "deleting" the first ***-provoking***. As you've pointed out yourself before, in the "space" of spoken forms, no-one can hear you hyphenate, apostrophize, etc.

Comment: _I enCOURage thotndiscushnprvoknQUEShnz by STUdents.

Comment: @John: Point taken, ty! I'm afraid I was just trying things on for size using the "voice in my head" - which apparently is better at *exaggerated* pauses and stress. It's only when you "spell it out" with the assistance of capitalization forcing the stress to be elsewhere AND wordsrunningtogether that I see (hear? :) how you do it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Such questions are usually hyphenated as [thought-provoking questions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thought-provoking%20questions%2Cthought%20provoking%20questions&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthought%20-%20provoking%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthought%20provoking%20questions%3B%2Cc0), and if you're going to delete elements in conjoined multiple consecutive *xxx-provoking* usages like this, standard practice is to at least repeat the hyphen...

> *I encourage **thought-** and **discussion-provoking questions** by students.*

Personally I would *not* advise reversing the order of ***thought*** and ***discussion*** here. The far stronger associations of the idiomatically commonplace usage linked to above can easily survive being interrupted by ***and discussion-***, but [***discussion-provoking questions***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thought-provoking%20questions%2Cdiscussion-provoking%20questions&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthought%20-%20provoking%20questions%3B%2Cc0) is relatively speaking such a rare collocation it would end up being "drowned out" (particularly if we consider the *spoken* context, where no-one can ***hear*** the hyphen that's supposed to resolve the very ambiguity OP seeks to avoid).

---

EDIT: Noting @jxh's comment below *(it seems odd to invent such a usage)*, and the fact that @Janus's "supporting" example involves compounds which wouldn't normally be hyphenated anyway, [here's a link to CMOS](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) (Chicago Manual of Style) endorsing *a group of **eight-** to **ten-year-olds***, which I think is essentially the same construction. (i.e. - I didn't "invent" it).

Comment: Your assumption here is that *thought* and *discussion* both qualify *provoking*. Rather than adopt your hernia-inducing punctuation, I would alter the syntax to say more-or-less the same thing in a different way. Of course, one possibility is that the meaning is *I encourage thought, and discussion-provoking questions*.

Comment: I upvoted because the use of hyphenation is another way to make the intention explicit. But, it seems odd to invent such a usage. Questions typically *promote* discussion, not *provoke* it.

Comment: @WS2: I don't see anything "[abreaction- or]  hernia-inducing" about the usage. Granted, there are potentially at least ***three*** different interpretations (1: encourage discussion and thought, where both activities  give rise to questions; 2: encourage both discussion-provoking questions and thought; 3: encourage questions which provoke either or both of thought and discussion). But #2 seems unlikely, to say the least, so I assume the disambiguation OP seeks is between #1 and #3 - which is easily done with just a couple of hyphens.

Comment: @WS2 I really don't think you can blame your hernia on Fumble’s punctuation here. It's perfectly standard and, I would say, the only punctuation that makes any sense here. It's really not that different from talking about, say, _mono- and ditransitive verbs_, except the fully written-out compound there is closed, not hyphenated.

Comment: @WS2, "... *thought* and *discussion* both qualify *provoking*" I agree that is probably what the OP *meant*, but I think your rewrite as "I encourage thought, and discussion-provoking questions by students" makes "thought" stand on its own. That seems odd in the context of the sentence, since thought without action has no external effects, even though encouraging students to think is clearly a good idea. I think the problem with the sentence is that the word "thought" is not an adjective. "I encourage *thoughtful* and discussion provoking questions by students" needs no punctuation.

Comment: @alephzero: That's a very good point. Changing *thought* to *thoughtful* provides a completely unambiguous way of conveying what I assume is OP's intended meaning, that easily works in speech as well. But on the downside, OP did want a "punctuation-only" solution if possible, *and* even a "non-pedant" such as myself would normally expect to see ***discussion-provoking*** hyphenated when used adjectivally before a noun.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you invented the hyphenation construct. I meant that "discussion-provoking" is not idiomatic.

Comment: @jxh: But I didn't "invent" that either! Grammatically, I'd say the hyphen is actually *required* in OP's context (given that he's explained exactly what he wants the text to *mean*). All I did there was correct the punctuation for that two-word term so it complies with standard orthographic principles in written English.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply *you* invented anything (and by that I do not mean to imply you never invented anything either). "discussion-provoking" is rare enough that using it in parallel to the idiomatic usage of "thought-provoking question" is like inventing a usage of the term "discussion". But after more careful searching, I see it is used more often than I had assumed it would be (although still much more rare than "promote discussion").

Comment: @jxh: oic. Obviously it's true that the attributive compound adjective  *discussion-provoking* is nowhere near as common as *thought-provoking*, but I did specifically address that point when explaining why I would *not* reverse the two components in a repetitive construction involving "deletion". Anyway, this is ELU, not ELL. I assume OP is well aware of the massive difference in "idiomatic prevalence" for the two terms, and that *that's* why he chose to put them that way round in the first place (though he may not have been consciously aware of the exact principle guiding his choice).

Comment: @alephzero The phrases "_thoughtful questions_" and "_thought provoking questions_" mean different things. The first implies thought on the part of the questioner before asking, while the latter implies thought by the people hearing it.

Answer (score 4):

I would use ***thought-provoking***, so I would interchange *discussion* and *thought*:

> I encourage *discussion* and *thought-provoking* questions by students.

You are trying to imply *discussion-provoking*, which isn't idiomatic and is causing the confusion.

My suggestion is intentionally ambiguous, because I personally feel students should be permitted to initiate a discussion free from the constraint of needing to phrase it in the form of a question. If you insist that only questions are allowed to be the initiators of discussion, then I would reword:

> I encourage students to ask *thought-provoking* questions that *promote discussion*.

Comment: Better to make the construction parallel:  I encourage students to ask questions that provoke thought and prompt discussion.

Comment: @deadrat: I feel attempting a parallel construction makes the sentence appear artificial and hollow. But, I changed the wording to avoid the parallel issue.

Comment: I try not to gainsay people's declarations of how they feel, and I'll note in passing that my suggestion isn't an attempt at parallel construction, but rather one of those.  Perhaps it would help if I knew what you meant by "artificial and hollow."  Stilted and insincere?

Comment: @deadrat: Aye (caramba).

Comment: I will guess that the "Aye" is a statement of agreement.  The expression is "¡Ay, caramba!" which is not.  So I"m left with not really knowing what you mean let alone how parallel grammatical construction indicates the insincerity of an offer.  You asked for advice on punctuation, so I'm assuming your statement is written rather than spoken.

Comment: @deadrat: The parenthetical comment can be ignored, and there should have been a wink emoticon next to it. The construction "provoke thought and X discussion", where X can be something that connotes instigation, sounds artificial *to me*, because the natural phrases to use are "thought-provoking" and "promote discussion". So, things that try to make their usages parallel each other look artificially constructed, and thus lack sincerity.

Comment: Not to worry.  An emoticon would have been wasted on me:  I'm too old to understand, let alone use one.  You're the ultimate judge of your own usage, so I'd never say you're wrong about what sounds to you.  And I might even agree with you for the spoken word.  People ordinarily don't sound as though they've composed their own statements in ordinary conversation.  The written word is different, and to *me* efforts to make writing as unambiguous as possible is a sign or politeness and not insincerity.  I don't prize spontaneity in writing as much as I do in conversation.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key requirements stated by the OP was that he/she wanted to encourage questions that provoked **both** thought **and** discussion. Unfortunately, there is no existing punctuation to enforce this requirement. In printed form we can **bold**en the words, as I have here and emphasise them in speech, but this is not really punctuation. In practice, we have to use the word 'both' to convey this fact. I would suggest:

> I encourage questions by students that provoke both thought and
>   discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really intend to say that you only encourage a question if it provokes both thought and discussion? Fumblefingers' answer is the standard way to elide a repeated part of a hyphenated expression, so

> I encourage thought- and discussion-provoking questions by students

means the same as

> I encourage thought-provoking and discussion-provoking questions by students.

But this would normally be interpreted as encouraging questions which provoke thought or discussion (or both). To stress that both are required I would hyphenate the whole thing as a single compound adjective:

> I encourage thought-and-discussion-provoking questions by students.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply rearrange the order?

> I encourage questions by students, provoking thought and discussion.

Comment: -1 because OP specifically *says* he would ***like to leave it as is, and just punctuate it if possible.***  By implication, he doesn't *want* to rearrange the order (so for effectively the same reason I think @jxh has addressed a question that wasn't actually asked).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: While asker did specify a preference for punctuation changes only, the question did allow for word rearrangement. And while I didn't say why I didn't suggest a punctuation change, I did say why I answered with a rearrangement.

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't really registered OP's point *before* the sample text *(or if necessary, reword)*. I was just noting the stuff *after* the example.

Answer (score 0):

The [***serial comma***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma):

> I encourage thought, and discussion provoking questions by students.

Answer (score 0):

You want the questions to be both thought-provoking and discussion-provoking, you can be explicit and go with:

> I encourage thought-provoking and discussion-provoking questions by students.

Answer (score 0):

> *I encourage thought and discussion provoking questions by students.*
>
> I'd like to leave it as is, and just punctuate it if possible.

I think that you can leave it that way. It's clear what it means. If you wanted to separate out 'thought' then you would have to write something like,

*I encourage thought, and discussion-provoking questions, by students.*

**My Answer**

The original version is perfectly fine.